# How to Disable Inventory Management In Magento 2.x

Tags: magento2, module, command-line, linux, uninstall-module

It may be necessary to disable Inventory Management modules to:

- Speed up the upgrade process for merchants migrating from 2.0.x, 2.1.x, or 2.2.x to 2.3.x.
- Use custom or third party inventory and order management modules.
- Use Magento Order Management for inventory and order management. The current Order Management connector does not support Inventory Management interfaces.

I am attempting to follow the official Magento instructions to disable inventory management modules. I have disabled modules from the command line previously and I am comfortable doing that. However, [the instructions](https://devdocs.magento.com/extensions/inventory-management/#disable-inventory-management) are not clear to me. They say,

"To disable Inventory Management, see the instructions for Enable or disable modules."

I understand the generic steps. I need the specific steps. Can I use the `inventory-composer-metapackage` to uninstall? If so, a specific example would help.

Even though it seemed wrong, I contemplated this:

```
bin/magento module:disable inventory-composer-metapackage
```

But I checked first and that is clearly wrong because:

```
bin/magento module:status inventory-composer-metapackage
Module does not exist
```

I'm running Magento 2.3.3 on CentOS 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to run below command to disable MSI modules in Magento 2.3+ versions.

To **disable** modules run below command

```
php bin/magento module:status | grep Magento_Inventory | grep -v List | grep -v None | grep -v -e '^$' | xargs php bin/magento module:disable
```

Or below one..

```
php bin/magento module:disable Magento_Inventory Magento_InventoryAdminUi Magento_InventoryApi Magento_InventoryGraphQl Magento_InventoryBundleProduct Magento_InventoryBundleProductAdminUi Magento_InventoryCache Magento_InventoryConfigurableProduct Magento_InventoryCatalogApi Magento_InventoryCatalog Magento_InventoryCatalogAdminUi Magento_InventoryCatalogSearch Magento_InventoryConfigurableProductAdminUi Magento_InventoryConfigurableProductIndexer Magento_InventoryConfiguration Magento_InventoryConfigurationApi Magento_InventoryDistanceBasedSourceSelection Magento_InventoryDistanceBasedSourceSelectionAdminUi Magento_InventoryDistanceBasedSourceSelectionApi Magento_InventoryElasticsearch Magento_InventoryExportStock Magento_InventoryExportStockApi Magento_InventoryGroupedProduct Magento_InventoryGroupedProductAdminUi Magento_InventoryGroupedProductIndexer Magento_InventoryImportExport Magento_InventoryIndexer Magento_InventoryLowQuantityNotification Magento_InventoryLowQuantityNotificationAdminUi Magento_InventoryLowQuantityNotificationApi Magento_InventoryMultiDimensionalIndexerApi Magento_InventoryProductAlert Magento_InventoryReservations Magento_InventoryReservationsApi Magento_InventoryReservationCli Magento_InventorySales Magento_InventorySalesAdminUi Magento_InventorySalesApi Magento_InventorySalesFrontendUi Magento_InventorySetupFixtureGenerator Magento_InventoryShipping Magento_InventoryShippingAdminUi Magento_InventorySourceDeductionApi Magento_InventorySourceSelection Magento_InventorySourceSelectionApi -f
```

To **enable** these modules you can run below command

```
php bin/magento module:status | grep Magento_Inventory | grep -v List | grep -v None | grep -v -e '^$' | xargs php bin/magento module:enable
```

Or below one...

```
php bin/magento module:enable Magento_Inventory Magento_InventoryAdminUi Magento_InventoryApi Magento_InventoryGraphQl Magento_InventoryBundleProduct Magento_InventoryBundleProductAdminUi Magento_InventoryCache Magento_InventoryConfigurableProduct Magento_InventoryCatalogApi Magento_InventoryCatalog Magento_InventoryCatalogAdminUi Magento_InventoryCatalogSearch Magento_InventoryConfigurableProductAdminUi Magento_InventoryConfigurableProductIndexer Magento_InventoryConfiguration Magento_InventoryConfigurationApi Magento_InventoryDistanceBasedSourceSelection Magento_InventoryDistanceBasedSourceSelectionAdminUi Magento_InventoryDistanceBasedSourceSelectionApi Magento_InventoryElasticsearch Magento_InventoryExportStock Magento_InventoryExportStockApi Magento_InventoryGroupedProduct Magento_InventoryGroupedProductAdminUi Magento_InventoryGroupedProductIndexer Magento_InventoryImportExport Magento_InventoryIndexer Magento_InventoryLowQuantityNotification Magento_InventoryLowQuantityNotificationAdminUi Magento_InventoryLowQuantityNotificationApi Magento_InventoryMultiDimensionalIndexerApi Magento_InventoryProductAlert Magento_InventoryReservations Magento_InventoryReservationsApi Magento_InventoryReservationCli Magento_InventorySales Magento_InventorySalesAdminUi Magento_InventorySalesApi Magento_InventorySalesFrontendUi Magento_InventorySetupFixtureGenerator Magento_InventoryShipping Magento_InventoryShippingAdminUi Magento_InventorySourceDeductionApi Magento_InventorySourceSelection Magento_InventorySourceSelectionApi -f
```

After running first command you need to run below deployment commands once

```
rm -rf generated/* var/view_preprocessed/* var/page_cache/*
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Thank you. I will accept answer as soon as it allows me.

Comment: It doesn't work for me: When upgrading I get the following error `Updating modules:
Dependency declaration 'cataloginventory_stock' in 'catalogsearch_fulltext' to the non-existing indexer.` After that message, the upgrade-command fails.

Answer (score 0):

Just an update to previous comment, for compartibility with 2.4+. Added multiple new modules.

```
php bin/magento module:disable Magento_Inventory Magento_InventoryAdminUi Magento_InventoryApi Magento_InventoryGraphQl Magento_InventoryBundleProduct Magento_InventoryBundleProductAdminUi Magento_InventoryCache Magento_InventoryConfigurableProduct Magento_InventoryCatalogApi Magento_InventoryCatalog Magento_InventoryCatalogAdminUi Magento_InventoryCatalogSearch Magento_InventoryConfigurableProductAdminUi Magento_InventoryConfigurableProductIndexer Magento_InventoryConfiguration Magento_InventoryConfigurationApi Magento_InventoryDistanceBasedSourceSelection Magento_InventoryDistanceBasedSourceSelectionAdminUi Magento_InventoryDistanceBasedSourceSelectionApi Magento_InventoryElasticsearch Magento_InventoryExportStock Magento_InventoryExportStockApi Magento_InventoryGroupedProduct Magento_InventoryGroupedProductAdminUi Magento_InventoryGroupedProductIndexer Magento_InventoryImportExport Magento_InventoryIndexer Magento_InventoryLowQuantityNotification Magento_InventoryLowQuantityNotificationAdminUi Magento_InventoryLowQuantityNotificationApi Magento_InventoryMultiDimensionalIndexerApi Magento_InventoryProductAlert Magento_InventoryReservations Magento_InventoryReservationsApi Magento_InventoryReservationCli Magento_InventorySales Magento_InventorySalesAdminUi Magento_InventorySalesApi Magento_InventorySalesFrontendUi Magento_InventorySetupFixtureGenerator Magento_InventoryShipping Magento_InventoryShippingAdminUi Magento_InventorySourceDeductionApi Magento_InventorySourceSelection Magento_InventorySourceSelectionApi Magento_InventoryAdvancedCheckout Magento_InventoryBundleImportExport Magento_InventoryBundleProductIndexer Magento_InventoryCatalogFrontendUi Magento_InventoryConfigurableProductFrontendUi Magento_InventoryInStorePickupApi Magento_InventoryInStorePickupAdminUi Magento_InventoryInStorePickup Magento_InventoryInStorePickupGraphQl Magento_InventoryInStorePickupShippingApi Magento_InventoryInStorePickupQuote Magento_InventoryInStorePickupQuoteGraphQl Magento_InventoryInStorePickupSales Magento_InventoryInStorePickupSalesApi Magento_InventoryInStorePickupSalesAdminUi Magento_InventoryInStorePickupShipping Magento_InventoryInStorePickupShippingAdminUi Magento_InventoryRequisitionList Magento_InventoryInStorePickupFrontend Magento_InventorySwatchesFrontendUi Magento_InventoryVisualMerchandiser Magento_InventoryWishlist Magento_InventoryInStorePickupMultishipping Magento_InventoryInStorePickupWebapiExtension Magento_InventoryDefaultForCountrySourceSelectionAdminUi Magento_InventoryDefaultForCountrySourceSelection -f
```

After, quite standard:

```
rm -rf generated/* var/view_preprocessed/* var/page_cache/*
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile // depends on mode
```

Answer (score 0):

I had disable the modules for magento 2.4.3 with command line your wrote.
But after that the Swatch product image in the product list doesn't work
I receive error "Cannot instantiate interface StockItemConfigurationInterface" when i click on a color and when it try to refresh the image of product ...
do you have a solution to maintain core stock featuer disable but having the swatch color image who work ?

Thanks a lot