# Magento 2.3 Inventory Management with Linnworks Integration Stock Levels Not Updating from Linnworks

Tags: magento2, inventory, management

I'm running Magento 2.3.4 and have successfully integrated it with Linnworks.  However, I believe I need to disable the inventory management in Magento 2.3 in order for the Linnworks to update the stock levels.

I am using GoDaddy as my host... is there a way to run the below solution?  if not is there a way to disable it without going on the server where Linnworks will update the inventory stock levels (which it doesn't presently)?

Your help would be most appreciated.

I've seen this answer here ( [How to Disable Inventory Management In Magento 2.x](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/297106/how-to-disable-inventory-management-in-magento-2-x) ):
"You need to run below command to disable MSI modules in Magento 2.3+ versions.

Answer (score 0):

You CAN disable the inventory management without going server side to do it....

Manually changing the config.php file has the same effect.

The solution can be found here :--->   https://devdocs.magento.com/extensions/inventory-management/#disable-inventory-management